# If $a$ and $b$ are any constant, show that there exist $A$ and $B$ such that $a\sin\theta + b\cos\theta$ can be written as $A\sin(\theta+B)$

Tags: trigonometry

First I use addition formula to transform $A\sin(\theta+B)$ as follow
$$
\begin{align}
A\sin(\theta+B)&=A(\sin\theta\cos B + \cos\theta \sin B)\\
&=(A\cos B)\sin\theta+(A\sin B)\cos\theta\\
\end{align}
$$

and I stuck at here.

Answer (score 3):

Case-1: If both $a=0=b$, then $A=0$ gives the required result.

Case-2: If atleast one of them from $\{a,b\}$ is non-zero, then
$a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin \theta + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos \theta\right)$.

Since $\sin (\cdot)$ is a continuous fumction and $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \in \text{Range}(\sin(\cdot))= [-1,1]$, there exists $B\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \sin B.$ And then, $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \cos B$. So, we can write, $a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\cos B \sin \theta + \sin B \cos \theta\right) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}  \sin (\theta+ B).$ By taking $A = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ we get the rquired answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see pair $P:(A\cos B,A\sin B)$ can represent any pair of two real numbers, because it can be interpreted as a point with circular angle $B$ on a circle with radius $A>0$, and when $A=0$ this point is origin, so we can adjust $A\geq 0$ and $B\in R$ to let $P$ cover all possible values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I'd consider this essentially complete as a proof. Succinctly, $(A\cos B, A\sin B)$ expresses all points in the plane in polar coordinates, with $A\ge 0, B\in(-\pi,\pi]$ (values of $B$ outside of this range are redundant). However, I think an examiner would also definitely like to see an explicit construction of $A,B$ from $a,b$ using Pythagoras' theorem.